# Why file must be mut when call method in Rust?

Tags: rust

There is a rust method, like this:

```rust
fn read_username_from_file() -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    let username_file_result = File::open("hello.txt");

    let mut username_file = match username_file_result {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(e) => return Err(e),
    };

    let mut username = String::new();

    match username_file.read_to_string(&mut username) {
        Ok(_) => Ok(username),
        Err(e) => Err(e),
    }
}
```

My question is Why the variable `username_file` must be mut. I didn't modify it later.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but you have **very** verbose error handling. You could use the [? operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator) to gratly shorten tour funtion (to literally 3 lines) and make it more readable.

Answer (score 5):

Method [`std::io::Read::read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_string) takes `&mut self`. `username_file` is `File`, which implements `Read`, therefore you're calling the method with `&mut File` as a receiver. And the creation of `&mut T` requires the binding of type `T` (that is, `username_file`) to be either temporary or marked as `mut`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `username_file` contains a cursor that points to the current location in the file. When you read from it you move that cursor to the end of the read data, so that subsequent reads can pick up where you left off. This counts as modifying the `username_file` variable and is represented in the language by the fact that all reading methods in the [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html) trait apply to `&mut self` rather than `&self`.

In particular you're using [`read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_string), which moves the file cursor to the end of the file once it has filled the string.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html

> Note that, although read and write methods require a &mut File, because of the interfaces for Read and Write, the holder of a &File can still modify the file, either through methods that take &File or by retrieving the underlying OS object and modifying the file that way. Additionally, many operating systems allow concurrent modification of files by different processes. Avoid assuming that holding a &File means that the file will not change.